# List of environment variables used by msbuild, dotnet sdks, azure, kudu, etc

Tags: msbuild, environment-variables, .net-core, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines

So, this mostly came up for me while I've been fiddling with CI builds in VSTS and azure deployment.  Through various github issues, docs, stack questions, random blog posts, reading the source, etc. I run across different environment variables used by the tooling.  Recently, `DOTNET_*` ones like:

- `DOTNET_SKIP_FIRST_TIME_EXPERIENCE` - which tells the build agent not to cache packages.  Since hosted agents dump the cache anyway, this is suggested in a note in the docs as a performance boost.
- `DOTNET_CONFIGURE_AZURE` - which tells the `_WebConfigTransform` target to set the `web.config`'s `stdoutlogfile` to `\\?\%home%\LogFiles\stdout`

others come up through azure web apps and configuration there:

- `WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION`
- `WEBSITE_SITE_NAME`
- There are other `WEBSITE_*`
- `DIAGNOSTICS_AZUREBLOBCONTAINERSASURL`
- There are other `DIAGNOSTICS_*`
- `KUDU_*` and `SCM_*` I've seen for manipulating aspects of the hosting environment and kudu environment underneath the web app
- When I go to KUDU console and check the environment variables there, I also see `AZURE_*`, more `DOTNET_*`, and a bunch of others

I recognize that each prefix is designating a 'namespace' of sorts that describe related sets of environment variables, so I'm unlikely to find a master location with info about all of them.

**But my question is for each of these domains, where can one find some sort of definitive list or even a general list of important environment variables and their functions?**

I feel like my path to understanding these settings and flags is very much random collision based, generating lots of heat with little real work accomplished. I'd rather be on an acyclic, weighted, directed graph to the answers, know what I mean? Even if I'm just greedily looking for the shortest path, it seems better than googling around for different issues and just stumbling upon things buried deep in the github repos or blog posts.  Can someone give me an edge here?

The context for this is that after I upgraded to netcore1.1/vs2017/csproj and my CI builds stopped transforming my web.config `stdoutlogfile` path correctly for azure web app deployment, I ended up having to dig down into the websdk source and back track through a few variable substitutions to find where the target was determining what environment variable to use when configuring a publish for Azure.  I was hoping to find some page in the docs for `dotnet publish` with a "here are the environment variables which can affect the output of the publish command" section, but came up empty handed.

Comment: I've torn up the internet looking for the same information. I haven't been able to find a definitive list. My thoughts are to see if there's an Azure Powershell command that will iterate all build variables, then include that as a task in the VSTS build process and capture the list in the output. 
My second thought is to look at the vsts-build tag in StackOverflow and see the recent and all time high posters who work at MSFT. I noticed starain-MSFT is listed. When I've tagged members of the Microsoft team who work on the product and monitor these subs, I've usually gotten a good response.

Comment: One more: I've found @AzureSupport to be extremely responsive on Twitter for these types of issues where documentation doesn't seem to exist. While the person monitoring the account likely won't know, they've always escalated the question to an engineer and gotten me an answer.

Comment: Thank you for that, a little less random bouncing that way and not feeling alone in this is cathartic.  My brute force solution idea is to go through every git repo and search for the prefixes and start recording where they're used, but golly there's just got to be some internal MSFT list or something, how do the devs keep track of it all themselves?

Comment: It is not just my impression, `.net` is loosing overview, and all this heat is more likely a patch/hotfix than true environment vars  Going to try the undocumented `ALLOW_5MINUTES_COFFE_BREAK_FOR_DEVELOPERS` now...

Comment: I am a VSTS dev and I can confirm that there is no "complete" list of env vars that includes all the possible build tools that VSTS is capable of running. VSTS is just a build orchestrator. Here is the link to all the VSTS env vars that available in the build. I know this isn't the list you are looking for, but perhaps others can post links to any other docs they find here as well.   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/build/variables?tabs=batch

Answer (score 0):

At least for App Service, here's a pretty good list - has `SCM-*` and some other , more deployment focused variables as well.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/reference-app-settings

A few more Kudu specific ones can be found here

https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Configurable-settings

There's also this little list of `AZURE_` variables in the SDK design guide:

https://azure.github.io/azure-sdk/general_azurecore.html#environment-variables